# How to solve gradle transitive dependency with credentials?

Tags: android, maven, build, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently has two Android project, SDK and App. In SDK there's several dependencies stores in my private artifactory, which need credentials to access. I put the credential in SDK's gradle file.

In App layer, when I try to pull the SDK and transitively solve the dependencies, I can't get access to those dependencies. It's like gradle don't even know to look up these dependencies in my artifactory. Btw, other dependencies in SDK which pull from maven or Jcenter works just fine.

So how could I solve this thing? These dependencies are third party so I can't put them on public. Please help me about it if you know how. Very thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the repository with credential also in your app module.

```
 repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'xxxx'
                password 'xxxxx'
            }
            url 'xxxx'
        }
```

Since some dependencies are located in the private repository you have to add this url to the repository block in the module.
It can't know the credentials.

Comment: Yes I understand, that's exactly what I'm doing right now. However the situation is, we only want to publish our SDK and people who use it can't pull from our artifatory.

Comment: @Ray It is clear, but gradle downloads the sdk and all its dependencies. If a dependency is stored in a private maven repo, you have to add the repo in build.gradle, there is no other way.